# leer valores dentro de un archivo json python 3.8.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, lista, diccionarios

estoy intentando leer {"user":"abc@mail.com"} y {"pass": "abcxyz"} en este archivo json

```
{
  "youtube": [
    {
      "user": "abc@mail.com",
      "pass": "abcxyz"
    }
  ]
}
```

puedo leer la lista "youtube" y me retorna:

```
  [
    {
      "user": "abc@mail.com",
      "pass": "abcxyz"
    }
  ]
```

pero no se como acceder a los valores de la lista, este es mi codigo

```
import json

with open('data.json') as f:
  datos = json.load(f)

print(datos["youtube"]) # esta linea me retorna user y pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso con `datos["youtube"]` accedes a:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y como puedes ver al inicio y final de la linea se encuentran `[]`, lo que te indica que es una lista, así que primero debes obtener el elemento llamando su posición en este caso `0`, quedaría algo así:

```
datos["youtube"][0]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como puedes ver ahora esta entre `{}`, que ahora si es un objeto json, donde podrias llamar sus atributos, en el caso que deses `user`:

```
datos["youtube"][0]["user"]
```

Comment: esta bien pero solo funciona al poner '' y no "" ;)

Comment: comillas simples*